# Exist foreign key depend 2 primary key?

Tags: c#, sql

As question title. Example: i have 3 table employee,teacher,student.

one employee's FOREIGN KEY depend student's PRIMARY KEY

one employee's FOREIGN KEY depend teacher's PRIMARY KEY

I tried but i couldn't.

Comment: What you couldn't do?

Comment: I suspect you may have a data relationship backwards.  Among other things, is it possible for someone to be both a teacher _and_ a student?

Comment: @claudio Redi: foreign key this table refer primary key two other table

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: i want code ID's student and code ID's teacher become account's employee

Comment: If I was previously a student in your system, then my school decided that (while I was still a student!) they wanted me to teach a class, what would happen?  What data is in `student` that is _also_ in `teacher`?

Comment: sorry, my purpose is use  code ID's student and code ID's teacher to login website school. You can way to make this

Comment: my problem here: 3 table TAIKHOAN,table NHANVIEN, table GIANGVIEN. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8OGy7vP_4y_VXY1aHpBczJIRXc/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant have a foreign key linking to two tables.

if you have control over the table structure it might make more sense to have a different structure

```
table: Person
table: EmployeeInfo (all information about being an employee i.e. EmpNo, ClockNo etc) with a foreign key on Person
table: TeacherInfo (all information about being a teacher i.e. HomeRoom, subject etc) with a foreign key on Person
table: StudentInfo (all information about a student i.e. course, funding type etc) with a foreign key on Person
```

that way with some simple joins you can get all teachers that are employees, or all students that are employees, or all employees that are neither teachers nor students

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question:

Can 1 Foreign Key refer to 2 different tables?

Answer: No, it cannot.

You can (and probably should) easily define 2 separate foreign keys:

- Employee IS|HAS Student
- Employee IS|HAS Teacher

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a people table that is the parent table and then child tables students, teachers and employees which would have foreign keys from their primary key to the people table. eg:

```
CREATE TABLE people
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  first_name character varying(128) NOT NULL,
  last_name character varying(128) NOT NULL,
   -- other columns appropriate to a person
  CONSTRAINT people_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


CREATE TABLE students
(
  fk_person bigint NOT NULL,
   -- other columns appropriate to the student
  CONSTRAINT students_pk PRIMARY KEY (fk_person),
  CONSTRAINT students_fk FOREIGN KEY (fk_person)
  REFERENCES people (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE teachers
(
  fk_person bigint NOT NULL,
   -- other columns appropriate to the teacher
  CONSTRAINT teachers_pk PRIMARY KEY (fk_person),
  CONSTRAINT teachers_fk FOREIGN KEY (fk_person)
  REFERENCES people (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE employees
(
  fk_person bigint NOT NULL,
   -- other columns appropriate to the employee
  CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (fk_person),
  CONSTRAINT employees_fk FOREIGN KEY (fk_person)
  REFERENCES people (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

You could also add a discriminator column to people to allow you to distinguish between students and teachers and a check (or trigger) on the discriminator column in employees to ensure that only teachers and students are put in that table. For more on discriminator columns take a look at the [hibernate documents](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html)